# understanding rol/ror pseudo-instructions mips

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, cpu-registers

I am using qtspim to practice on logical operations.I have a question about **rol/ror** pseudo-instructions.When i run the code below on qtspim the register's content changes to *$t1=0x34567812*.

```
    li $t0,0x12345678    
    rol $t1,$t0,8
```

Question:Shouldn't it be  *$t1=0x12345678* instead? We are rotating 8 bits left so the numbers move 8 bits ending up in their original positions.(?)

Comment: 8 bits = 2 hex digits = 1/4 of a 32-bit register.  1 hex digit = 1 nibble.  Rotating by 32 would be a no-op.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you very much!! :)